# Firebase Bucket

Tags: c#, firebase, winforms, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload the Image on Firebase Storage but I face some problems with it.

```
ar storage = StorageClient.Create();
               
                string studentImageRef = bucket + 33333 + ".jpg";

                var obj = storage.GetObject(studentImageRef, studentImageRef);
                var downloadUrl = obj.MediaLink;

                await storage.UploadObjectAsync(obj, null, new UploadObjectOptions { PredefinedAcl = PredefinedObjectAcl.PublicRead });

                // Add the download URL to the student's information
                studentsInfo.ImageUrl = downloadUrl;
```

This is the error I encountered.

> Error: The service storage has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is NotFound. The specified bucket does not exist

And yes I tried several times and make sure the bucket name is correct but the error still persists.

Comment: Is your bucket exist in with correct name in Firebase Storage

Comment: Yes, i already tried gs://xxxx.appspot.com/ and xxxxx.appspot.com/ but still the same

Comment: *I tried several times and make sure the bucket name is correct* - you should edit the question to show your tries.  We can't see the name of your bucket or the code you used for that.  IN particular, we can't see the value of `bucket` and that it matches the actual name of your bucket.

Comment: string bucket = "gs://my-bucket.appspot.com/";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured how to fix this problem using this codes

```
/ Convert image to stream
                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                imageFile.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                stream.Position = 0;

                // Initialize Google Cloud Storage
                var storage = StorageClient.Create();

                string studentImageRef = "my-bucket.appspot.com/" + Lname_FnameGetter + ".jpg";

                await storage.UploadObjectAsync("my-bucket.appspot.com/", studentImageRef, "image/jpeg", stream, new UploadObjectOptions { PredefinedAcl = PredefinedObjectAcl.PublicRead });

                // Get the download URL for the image
                var obj = storage.GetObject("my-bucket.appspot.com", studentImageRef);
                var downloadUrl = obj.MediaLink;

                // Add the download url to the student's information
                studentsInfo.ImageUrl = downloadUrl;
```

The ff. codes i provide solve the problem.